# AbstractTableModel DELETE row not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

i have this table model, and i insert values calling in this way:

```
lista.setModel(new SimpleTableModel(dados, colunas));
```

lista is the JTable

the Model:

```
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class SimpleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{  

    private ArrayList linhas = null;  
    private String [] colunas = null;  
    public String[] getColunas() {return colunas;}  
    public ArrayList getLinhas() {return linhas;}  
    public void setColunas(String[] strings) {colunas = strings;}  
    public void setLinhas(ArrayList list) {linhas = list;}
    @Override
    /** 
     * Retorna o numero de colunas no modelo 
     * @see javax.swing.table.TableModel#getColumnCount() 
     */  
    public int getColumnCount() {return getColunas().length;}  

    /** 
     * Retorna o numero de linhas existentes no modelo 
     * @see javax.swing.table.TableModel#getRowCount() 
     */  
    public String getColumnName(int col){  
        return getColunas()[col];  
    }  

    public int getRowCount() {return getLinhas().size();}  

    /** 
     * Obtem o valor na linha e coluna 
     * @see javax.swing.table.TableModel#getValueAt(int, int) 
     */  
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {  
        // Obtem a linha, que é uma String []  

        String [] linha = (String [])getLinhas().get(rowIndex); 

        // Retorna o objeto que esta na coluna  
        return linha[columnIndex];  
    }  
//added this to try...
    public boolean deleteLine(int line){   
        linhas.remove(line);   
        return true;   
    }   

    public boolean deleteAll(){   
        linhas.clear();   
        return true;   
    }   


public SimpleTableModel(ArrayList dados, String[] colunas){  
    setLinhas(dados);  
    setColunas(colunas);  
}  

}
```

but the problem is, i CANT call the deleteLine()....

```
    public boolean deleteLine(int line){   
        linhas.remove(line);   
        return true;   
    }   

    public boolean deleteAll(){   
        linhas.clear();   
        return true;   
    }
```

i dont know how to make this to work... since i cant access

i think the mistake is that the Constructor is the one that "populate" the table, i think i have to change it and create a insertLine()..

but not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe would be that `deleteLine()` is a method that belongs to `simpleTableModel`, but you aren't creating any instance of that `simpleTableModel` on the frame. You are doing directly

```
lista.setModel(new SimpleTableModel(dados, colunas));
```

Try doing in your frame:

```
SimpleTableModel modelo = new SimpleTableModel(dados, colunas);
lista.setModel(modelo);
modelo.deleteX(line);
```

And inside your model something like this:

```
public boolean deleteX(int line) throws DAOExcepcion{ //could be void because always returns true
        this.removeRow(line);
        this.fireTableRowsDeleted(line, line);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your not firing any kind of event from the model that would tell the table that the model has changed.

Try using [`fireTableRowsDeleted`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29) after you have removed the rows from the underlying data structure within the model

Take a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#) and [Firing Data Change Events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire) in particular